# Angular async pipe not working with fromEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7vlnu

I am creating an `Observable` from an `HTMLAudioElement` using `fromEvent`:

```
playTime(): Observable<any> {
    return fromEvent(myMediaElement, 'play').pipe(
        map(e => e.type + Date.now())
    );
}
```

`playTime()` gets passed to a child component via an `@Input()`

In the component, when I subscribe:

```
// component.ts

@Input() currentTime: Observable<any>;

playDate = '';

ngOnInit {
    this.currentTime.subscribe(v => this.playDate = v);
}
```

```
// component.html

// will render
{{ playDate }}  

// will not render
{{ currentTime | async }}
```

I tried ye olde `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and `Application.tick()` to no avail.

Something I need to know about `fromEvent` and the way the subscription works? Other Observables constructed from `BehaviorSubject` work fine in this component

Comment: Would you mind creating a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/) so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Strange pattern, why don't you simply store the `playDate` on the parent and pass it to the child as a `@Input()` property?

Comment: stackblitz added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your Stackblitz. It's not a good practice that you are passing a service function as an @Input() by ***directly*** referencing the service from the template.

Therefore, instead of referencing the service in a template like your currently do:

```
<audio-container [currentTime]="audio.currentTime()">
```

You should create a new Observable which will reference to the one from a service, and then use it in a template.

```
<audio-container [currentTime]="$currentTime">
```

app.component.ts

```
$currTime: Observable<any>;

constructor(public audio: AudioPlayerService) {
  this.$currentTime = this.audio.currentTime();
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8npcbh)

**ADVICE**: Don't reference the service variables / functions directly from a template.

*BAD:*

```
<button (click)="audio.play(version1)">Play Song 1</button>
```

*GOOD:*

```
<button (click)="play(version1)">Play Song 1</button>

play(version) {
   this.audio.play(version).subscribe(...);
}
```

Comment: @Friso Hoekstra You're welcome. Also check my edit with an advice.

Comment: It's funny that the direct reference would work with an Observable created from a BehaviorSubject, but not with one created with fromEvent. Why is that?